Lombok- cannot find symbol
I'have updated my Spring Boot 2.5.x project to 3.0.0.
When I run a clean install I got a few error saying "cannot find symbol".
For example on this method:
  public ReviewResult getBody() {
            ReviewResult reviewResult = new ReviewResult();
            reviewResult.setReviewAnswer("RED");
            reviewResult.setReviewRejectType("RETRY");
            reviewResult.setModerationComment("We do not accept screenshots. Please upload an original photo.");
            reviewResult.setClientComment("Screenshots are not accepted.");
            reviewResult.setRejectLabels(Lists.newArrayList("UNSATISFACTORY_PHOTOS", "SCREENSHOTS"));

            return reviewResult;
        }

The IntelliJ shows an error for every setter.
The ReviewResult class is the following:
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
public class ReviewResult {
    private String moderationComment;
    private String clientComment;
    private String reviewAnswer;
    private List<String> rejectLabels;
    private String reviewRejectType;
}

The pom.xml is the following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hu.dolphio</groupId>
    <artifactId>tokeportal-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>travel-backend</name>
    <description>Travel Backend application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>travel-release</id>
            <name>travel release repository</name>
            <url>http://sw-services.domain:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>travel-snapshot</id>
            <name>travel snapshot repository</name>
            <url>http://sw-services.domain:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.34</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>      
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <embeddedLaunchScriptProperties>
                        <mode>service</mode>
                    </embeddedLaunchScriptProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                            <version>5.0.0</version>
                            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
                        </path>
                          <dependency>
                            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>travel -release</id>
        <name>travel release repository</name>
        <url>http://sw-services.domain:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>travel-snapshot</id>
        <name>travelsnapshot repository</name>
        <url>http://sw-services.domain:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

Why do I get this error message and how to solve it?

Perhaps you are missing the annotationProcessorPaths entry for Lombok in the maven-compiler-plugin section:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
      [...]
      <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.34</version>
      </path>
      [...]
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

Moreover, there is that dependency tag for jakarta.persistence-api that I suspect is not correct to place in the annotationProcessorPaths section.
